# What is the recommended way to connect to CloudSQL (or PubSub etc) in a GAE custom runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to deploy a multi-service application on GAE using custom runtimes.

I've everything set, my service expects some environment variable to know when to connect to the database and other services.

But I can't see anywhere in the doc where it explains how to connect to other Google Cloud service from a custom runtime.

If it is explained, thanks for pointing me there. if not, can someone who has been successful on doing that explain to me how he/she achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for connecting from Flexible Environment apps is found in [Cloud SQL > Documentation > MySQL > Connecting from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine). Some of the languages (for example, for python) make use of the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy), while others (such as java) don't.

As for Pub/Sub, you can read about client libraries in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries).

Comment: Is there a proxy for  pubsub and those other services?

Comment: Ah, apologies for not being more general. I've updated my answer.